# How to extend \ change \ customize the look and feel of AdaptiveCards?

Tags: javascript, c#, css, botframework, adaptive-cards

We were able to release a working bot chat app within out company and all is good. But our UX team wants to make it look even better.  I understand that there is a botchat.css which is part of the webChat component and we have made required changes to make it look as per the branding. But they have a few specific requirement.

for example, when there are more than 4 cards, we show it as carousel. UX team, wants to change this behavior and display 4 tiles. Out of which, first 3 tiles will be thumbnails and then 4th one will be "number" of remaining cards. (just like FB or What's App shows, when it has more pictures to show). Then when the user clicks on this 4th tile, it will open up a different screen/popup and show all the cards as list with a back button.

I understand that I probably dig around and find a way to do this through C# code and create columnSets and put these images as explained above, with help of adaptiveCards.io site. With the help of those samples we were able to deliver the first version of our app and was very helpful.

What I am looking for is some high level opinion about what options we have to customize the look and feel of the client. 
How about HostConfig? is it even an option?

thanks

Comment: At first glance, I do not see a way to do what you are asking with any channel other than direct line (with a custom interface) or webchat (customized).